# Why I'm getting an error when creating a npm package

Tags: node.js, npm

I am new with NPM. Below hackerrank question is asking next:

Create the file package.json using npm commands

The name of the app should be npm_package.
Tha start point will be index.js.
The project should have the following elements of dependencecies

- Install the latest version of react
- Lodash with major version 4 and minor version 17
- Redux with Major version 4
- Mocha dor testing in Dev
- Eslint with major version 6 in Dev

So, I tried these commands but it was marked as fail

```
mkdir npm_package

cd npm_package

npm init

npm install react --save

npm install lodash@4.17.0 --save

npm install redux@4.0.0 --save

npm install mocha --save-dev

npm install eslint@6.0.0 --save-dev
```

What I am missing? Below is the result:

```
grep: /projects/challenge/package.json: No such file or directory

grep: /projects/challenge/package.json: No such file or directory

find: ‘/projects/challenge/node_modules’: No such file or directory

grep: /projects/challenge/package.json: No such file or directory


Test cases executed = 4
PASS = 0   FAIL=4


**challenge/npm_package$ ls**

**node_modules  package.json  package-lock.json**
```

Answer (score 0):

To initialize to the default package.json we have to supply the -y flag:
`npm init -y`

Comment: that is not the issue

Comment: The project root would be `npm_package` and not `challenge`.

Comment: That is the path:  **...challenge/npm_package$** the proyect is npm_package,
then I listed the content
**challenge/npm_package$ls
node_modules  package.json  package-lock.json** --this is the output

But the test result gave this:

grep: /projects/challenge/package.json: No such file or directory

grep: /projects/challenge/package.json: No such file or directory

find: ‘/projects/challenge/node_modules’: No such file or directory

grep: /projects/challenge/package.json: No such file or directory


**Test cases executed = 4
PASS = 0   FAIL=4**

Comment: In which directory are you executing the commands? If you create a directory `npm_package` and then change to this directery, create a project inside this directory and install packages, then Node will create files named `package.json` and `package-lock.json` in this directory and a folder named `node_modules` inside this directory in which all packages will be installed. If I assume that you are in the `/projects` folder, then you would see your directory with the command `ls /projects/npm_package`. I assume that you are using bash for this.